# if statement for matched values based on dates in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a data frame where I essentially have an ID#, a year, and a status code. Here is an example of it:

```
> df <- data.frame(ID=c(100,100,100,102,102,102), 
                   Year=c(2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012),
                   Status=c("c","d","d","d","c","c"))
> df
   ID Year Status
1 100 2010      c
2 100 2011      d
3 100 2012      d
4 102 2010      d
5 102 2011      c
6 102 2012      c
```

I want to add a 4th column (`df$def`) as a binary based on the ID#'s status, however, once the status is "d" I need that to carry through the remaining years despite the status potentially changing to "c". I can write the simple IF statement to have a 0 for "c" and 1 for "d", but am having trouble factoring the dates moving forward.

I would like the final table to look like this:

```
 df
   ID Year Status Def
1 100 2010      c   0
2 100 2011      d   1
3 100 2012      d   1
4 102 2010      d   1
5 102 2011      c   1
6 102 2012      c   1
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
  within(df, {def<- ave(Status=='d', ID, FUN=cumsum);def[def>1] <- 1 })
  #   ID Year Status def
  #1 100 2010      c   0
  #2 100 2011      d   1
  #3 100 2012      d   1
  #4 102 2010      d   1
  #5 102 2011      c   1
  #6 102 2012      c   1
```

Or for bigger dataset, you could use `data.table`

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(df)[, Def:=cumsum(Status=='d'), by=ID][ Def>1, Def:=1][]
  #    ID Year Status Def
 #1: 100 2010      c   0
 #2: 100 2011      d   1
 #3: 100 2012      d   1
 #4: 102 2010      d   1
 #5: 102 2011      c   1
 #6: 102 2012      c   1
```

Or you could use `split`

```
  res <- unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) {
              indx <- which(x$Status=='d')
              x$Def <- 0
              if(length(indx)>0){
              indx1 <- indx[1] 
               x$Def[indx1:nrow(x)] <- 1
               }
               x}), df$ID)



   res
   #   ID Year Status Def
   #1 100 2010      c   0
   #2 100 2011      d   1
   #3 100 2012      d   1
   #4 102 2010      d   1
   #5 102 2011      c   1
   #6 102 2012      c   1
```

Comment: The top code worked best with my code. Not sure about the bottom one, my df had roughly 60,000 ID's and was taking to long to run. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @nciaf I think `ave` based solution would be faster compared to `split` with some additional checks.

Comment: @nciaf Consider the `data.table` approach (updated), would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the function `by()` to get the cumulative sum by ID (not allowing it to go over 1)

```
df$def <- ifelse(df$Status == "c", 0, 1)
df$def <- pmin(1, unlist(by(df$def, df$ID, cumsum)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
within(df, {
    Def <- 
    ave(as.character(Status), ID, 
        FUN=function(x) ifelse(seq_along(x) < which.max(x == 'd'), 0, 1))
})
#    ID Year Status Def
# 1 100 2010      c   0
# 2 100 2011      d   1
# 3 100 2012      d   1
# 4 102 2010      d   1
# 5 102 2011      c   1
# 6 102 2012      c   1
```